# asciidoc empty table rows

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I like to have a table in asciidoc, where there is an empty row in it.
The problem is, letting the row empty makes it very small automatically.

```
[cols="5,3,3"]
|===
|||
|===
```

I tried to fill the cells with spaces, `+` `s , line feeds, tabs. But there is no character I know, where the cell is empty on the paper and has the normal height.

What I mean is a css-like `min-height`, or a special character like `&nbsp;` in html.

So how to force an empty table row to have the normal line height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by myself:

```
[cols="5a,3,3"]
|===
|{nbsp} +
 {nbsp} +||
|===
```

The `a`in the column definition marks this column as asciidoc-content, so that asciidoc commands will work. The `{nbsp} +` is the magic keyword for an empty space, which is not like the normal space. The normal space will be ignored, the `{nbsp}` is not ignored.

Hope that helps for other cases too.

Found it here: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/wiki/How-to-insert-sequential-blank-lines

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems difficult. I hope you have good reasons to add an empty row.

Maybe a small hack might help you for the moment :-)

`[cols="5,3,3"]
|===
a|image:sunset.jpg[""]||
|===`

I just put an image which does not exists in the first column. Maybe a one pixel image might work as well. The `a` in front of `|`makes the asciidoctor interpreter to read it as asciidoctor.